# continuous and residual spectrum of the right shift

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $1\le p<q\le\infty$, $L:\ell^p\to\ell^p,x\mapsto(x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ and $R:\ell^q\to\ell^q,y\mapsto(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$.

It's easy to show $L'=R$, $\sigma(L)=\sigma(R)=\overline B_1(0)$, $\sigma_p(L)=B_1(0)$, $\sigma_r(L)=\emptyset$, $\sigma_c(L)=\partial B_1(0)$, $\sigma_p(R)=\emptyset$ and $B_1(0)\subseteq\sigma_r(R)$.

> But I'm failing to show that $\sigma_c(R)=\emptyset$. How can we do that?

Clearly, if $\lambda\in\sigma_c(R)$, then $\mathcal R(\lambda-R)$ is dense and hence $\lambda\not\in\sigma_p(L)$, i.e. $\lambda\in\partial B_1(0)$ ... But I'm not able to derive a contradiction from that.

Answer (score 1):

Since $q>1$, you have $R=L'$, considering $L$ acting on $L^p$ for $p$ conjugate to $q$.  From
$$
\|(R-\lambda I)x\|_p=\|Rx-\lambda x\|_p\geq\|Rx\|_p-|\lambda|\,\|x\|_p=(1-|\lambda|)\,\|x\|_p,
$$
we get that $R-\lambda I$ is bounded below for all $\lambda\in B_1(0)$. This precludes $\lambda$ from being an approximate eigenvalue. Combined with the fact that the boundary of the spectrum consists of approximate eigenvalues shows that $\sigma_{\rm ap}(R)=\partial B_1(0)$.

From $\sigma(R)=\sigma_r(R)\cup\sigma_{\rm ap}(R)$ we conclude that $B_1(0)\subset\sigma_r(R)$.

If $\lambda\in\partial B_1(0)$, then $ \lambda\not\in\sigma_p(L)$ (here we use $p<\infty$). This means that $\ker(L-\lambda I)=\{0\}$. It is well-known (proof at the end) that if an operator is injective, then its adjoint has dense range. So $\overline{\operatorname{ran}(R-\lambda I)}=\ell^q$,
showing that $\lambda\in\sigma_c(R)$. That is, $\partial B_1(0)\subset \sigma_c(R)$. We have
$$
\overline{B_1(0)}=\sigma(R)=\sigma_r(R)\cup\sigma_c(R)
$$
(since $\sigma_p(R)=\emptyset$). As $\sigma_r(R)$ and $\sigma_c(R)$ are disjoint, with $B_1(0)\subset\sigma_r(R)$ and $\partial B_1(0)\subset\sigma_c(R)$, it follows that
$$
\sigma_r(R)=B_1(0),\qquad \sigma_c(R)=\partial B_1(0).
$$

---

*Proof that $T:X\to Y$ is a bounded operator and $T'$ is injective, then $T$ has dense range.*

If $\operatorname{ran}T$ were not dense, there exists $y\in Y\setminus\overline{\operatorname{ran}T}$. By Hahn-Banach there exists $g\in Y'$ with $g(y)=1$ and $g(Tx)=0$ for all $x\in X$. This means that
$$
(T'g)(x)=g(Tx)=0
$$
for all $x$, so $T'g=0$. As $T'$ is injective, we get that $g=0$ a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's clear to me that $B_1(0)\subseteq\sigma_r(R)$ (missed that in the question). But how do we prove $\overline{\operatorname{ran}(R-\lambda I)}=\ker(T-\overline\lambda I)^\perp$ (and what is $T$? $T=L$ I guess)? (I'm curious, by the way, why you're considering $\overline\lambda$. I mean, we know that if $\lambda\in\partial B_1(0)$, then $\lambda\not\in B_1(0)=\sigma_p(L)$ and clearly $\overline\lambda\not\in\sigma_p(L)$ as well. So, I guess the point is the former identity ...)

Comment: The formula that I know, for a general bounded linear operator $T$ on a complex Banach space $X$, is $\overline{\mathcal R(T)}=(\mathcal N(T'))_\perp$. Now, if $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, then $(\lambda-T)'=\lambda-T'$ (**not** $\overline\lambda-T'$). Did you confuse that with the Hilbert space adjoint? My expectation would be $\sigma_c(R)=\emptyset$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tend to think about Hilbert spaces.

Comment: I'm on my phone right now, so I'll get back to this a bit later.

Comment: Thank you in advance for your effort.

Comment: I'm back, and I have edited the answer to address the adjoint part.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. The result you've proved at the end reminds me on the formula $\overline{\mathcal R(T)}=\mathcal N(T')_\perp$ (from which the result should immediately follow). Is it even an equivalence, i.e. can it be shown that $T$ (or $T'$) is injective iff $T'$ (or $T$) has dense range?

Comment: Did you notice that you've used the result with $T$ and $T'$ exchanged? Note that $L'=R$, but $R'\ne L$ (for example, if $q=\infty$, $(\ell^q)'\ne\ell^p$).

Comment: It is not true that if $T$ is injective then $T'$ has dense range; you only get weakly dense range. While $T'$ is injective if and only if $T$ has dense range.

Comment: The case $p=1$ might require a bit more care, I need to think about it.

Comment: Thanks for noting. What do you think of my 2nd comment? I think you cannot apply your result here. However, I was at least able to note the following: if $q\in(1,\infty)$ and $\lambda\in\partial B_1(0)$, then $y_n:=\frac1{n\lambda^{n-1}}$ is in $\ell^q$ (since $q>1$), but if $x\in\ell^q$ would be a solution of $(\lambda-R)x=y$, then $x_n=\frac1{\lambda^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda^{k-1}y_k$, while $|x_n|=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac1k=\infty$; which is a contradiction to $x\in\ell^q$. So, $\lambda-R$ is not surjective in that case. Maybe something simlar works for $q=1$ and $q=\infty$?

Comment: I think I need to revert that. If $q<\infty$, then $R'=L$ holds as well and hence your result is applicable. However, my direct argument above might lead to an idea for $q=\infty$?

Comment: Won't have time to correct the answer today. But note that the use of adjoints is for convenience. Both $R,L$ are defined for any $p,q$. If $|\lambda|=1$, then $L-\lambda$ is injective for all $p\in[1,\infty)$, so I think the argument works for most cases. I'll check later.

Comment: When $q=\infty$ the argument still applies. There is no situation above where one considers the dual of $\ell^\infty$. It would be different, I think, if you consider $q=1$.

Comment: Didn't you use $R'=L$? This is not true when $q=\infty$.

Comment: No, I used $R=L'$.

Comment: How did you utilize the result at the end of your answer then? You start with injectivity of $L$ and conclude that $R$ has dense range. But your result requires the dual $T'$ to be injective in order to conclude that $T$ has dense range. So $T=R$ and hence it seems like you've used $T'=R'=L$. I guess I'm missing something really obvious ...

Comment: (sorry for the very late reply).  As you say, I use that the adjoint of $L$ is $R$, and that $R$ is injective. I don't know why you say $T=R$.